# How to implement `-d 'value={"test":"test"}'` of curl in python?

Tags: python, curl

The following command can post the value to one of my internal web service.

```
curl -k -X POST -d 'value={"test":"test"}' "https://myinternalsite/....." -u 'username:password'
```

And I need a python script to implement so I have the following script:

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth


url='https://myInternalWebsite/....'
json={'test':'test'}
username='....'
password = '....'
auth = HTTPBasicAuth(username, password)
resp = requests.post(url, json=json, auth=auth, verify=False)
resp.content
```

The script finished without any error (200). But the `json` value is not posted. Not sure if the internal site cannot handle the `json=` parameter? How to implement `-d 'value={"test":"test"}'` of curl in python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the `json` argument it doesn't pass it as the value the `value` parameter, it sends the JSON as the raw POST body.

If it should be the value of a POST parameter, use the `data` argument and call `json.dumps()` explicitly.

```
resp = requests.post(url, data = {"value": json.dumps(json)}, auth=auth, verify=False)
```